# Signal loss over distance

Tags: audio

What diameter size copper wire is needed to send 30KHz audio at 50 watts over to high power tweeters 120 feet away without losing too much signal over the wire?

Comment: How much is too much?

Comment: if this is to repel/attract something with ultrasonic hearing, ordinary 5-10A figure 8 cable may be fine, 50 watts isn't that much power, ~4A at 12V, 1A @50V etc.

Comment: The opposite of gaining is losing not "loosing".

Comment: @JohnD, I am not the OP, but I fixed the typo. It is OK to fix typos.

Comment: @mkeith Thanks, I know, it's just that it seems no one can spell "losing" anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Rule of thumb is that you want your cables to have a resistance that is no more than 5% of your tweeter's impedance, otherwise the frequency response is adversely affected. But are you only sending 30 kHz? (which is ultrasonic). If you only care about that one frequency, then the loss may not matter.

Assuming your tweeters have an impedance of 4 ohms (you did not mention it, but it's important), then you want no more than .2 ohms over 240 feet (2x120). An AWG 9 cable has .808 ohms per 1000 feet, which is a hair under .2 ohms at 240 feet. So you would need AWG 9 or lower (thicker).

Of course, the maximum cable resistance is .4 ohms if the tweeters are 8 ohms, so AWG 12 or thicker would work.

It took me a while (it's been years), but I found the website where this is covered: http://www.roger-russell.com/wire/wire.htm

Comment: You are ignoring skin effect. The resistances at 30 kHz will be much higher than you are quoting due to skin effect.

Answer (score 0):

At 30 kHz and 120 ft length, inductance is important so it could be good to employ twisted or coaxial cables of the right ohmic size. Shielding should be considered if you have square wave drivers of the tweeter to avoid irradiation of harmonics. Also because of skin effect employ flexible cables.

Comment: Flexible cables will not help with skin effect unless the individual strands are insulated.

Comment: At these frequencies the oxide layer of copper is sufficient to guarantee a good behavior because insulates the single wire of strand. We employ currently standard cables at 20 to 40 kHz and some kW wth no problems. If you work at higher frequencies Litz wires are obviously better.

Answer (score 0):

At 30 kHz, you should consider skin effect. The resistance of AWG 12 wire at 30 kHz will be a lot higher than at DC. According to one online calculator, the AC resistance of 12 AWG wire is around 0.6 Ohms over 75m (roughly 240 feet). The same wire at 1 kHz is 0.4 Ohms.

The skin effect depth at 30 kHz is around 0.375mm, meaning that wire over around 0.75mm diameter will not be utilized completely. For reference, AWG 20 is around 0.8mm. So I would suggest using multiple strands of AWG 20 wire to lower your wire impedance to whatever value you find acceptable. According to the site, 75 meters of AWG 20 is around 2.5 Ohms. So you could use around 5 strands to get down to 0.5 Ohms.

Here is the site:

http://chemandy.com/calculators/round-wire-ac-resistance-calculator.htm

Comment: At these frequencies the oxide layer of copper is sufficient to guarantee a good behavior because insulates the single wire of strand. We employ currently standard cables at 20 to 40 kHz and some kW wth no problems. If you work at higher frequencies Litz wires are obviously better.

Comment: @krufra, really? I did not know that. So all that is needed is to use multi-strand wire, which is the usual choice anyway. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, there is a limit to about 2.5 sq mm because copper oxide insulates up to about .2 V ( Schottky barrier). When the current is higher and requires more area the transverse voltage is greater so losses increase strongly. We prefer silicone rubber cables because their production process cooks the copper to brown color so the oxide is very strong.